# Kuratowski definition of finite sets: terminology and notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, terminology

$\DeclareMathOperator{\fspan}{fspan}$

For any set $U$, there is a set comprising the empty set and the singletons of elements of $U$,
that is,

$$\{\emptyset\} \cup \{A\ \colon \exists a, a \in U \land \{a\} = A\}.$$

For the moment, call this the *base set of $U$*.  Now some set is the closure under union of the base set.  We define $U$ as *Kuratowski-finite* or *Kuratowski-infinite* according as that closure does or does not contain $U$; that done, the closure turns out to be just the set of finite subsets of $U$.

Is there any accepted name or notation for this construct, that is, the closure under union of the base set of $U$?  Not knowing any such, I've been calling it the "finite span of $U$", and writing it "$\fspan(U)$"; if there is any established convention I'd be glad to follow it.

Also: The construct can be defined as the least superset, closed under union, of the base set of $U$.  It would be good to have a general name for supersets, closed under union, of the base set, since they're so often needed in working with Kuratowski finiteness.  The best I've come up with so far is "finite prespan of $U$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term span is absolutely fine, since if you view $\mathcal P(U)$ as a vector space over $\{0,1\}$, then this is the span of the singletons in that context.

I am not aware of any terminological or notational convention, and as long as you define your notation, that's absolutely fine. Since you wrote $\{A:\exists a,a\in U\land\{a\}=A\}$, instead of just $\{\{a\}\mid a\in U\}$, I suspect that you were probably thorough enough to define the notation where you have used it.

In principle you could say that it is the ideal generated by the singletons, that will also work. And it is indeed the ideal from a ring theoretic point of view (viewing $\mathcal P(U)$ as an algebra, not just a vector space, over $\{0,1\}$).

As for a global term for a superset which is closed under some operation, you might not find something that is accepted across the board. It's not a bad idea to be verbose and just say "a set containing bla and closed under some operation".